# Blender Grease Pencil is rendering all black

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

I'm completely stumped as to what's going on here but for whatever reason when I render this scene in blender it just shows up all black. It does not show up like this in any other of the render modes only when I render it for export. Also another weird thing, I was able to render the scene before just fine. I've included some pictures. I would include the file but I'm not entirely sure how.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the exchange, just to confirm the items are Grease Pencil objects and not image planes?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I did end up finding a solution of sorts. The problem seemed to stem from the world lighting, so I deleted that and created a new one which seemed to solve the issue. Why it was suddenly causing the issue I don't entirely know, as I hadn't touched the world lighting prior to that point.